# Как узнать имя пользователя или email в onedrive sdk?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, onedrive

Как, используя `OneDriveClientExtensions`, узнать имя отображаемое пользователя или email.

```
string[] scopes = { "onedrive.readwrite" };
IOneDriveClient OneDriveClient = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes);
await OneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
```

Comment: `var userProfile = await client.GetMeAsync(); var mail = userProfile.Emails.Preferred;`

Comment: `IOneDriveClient` не содержит метода `GetMeAsync`. Версия библиотеки 1.1.29.

Comment: https://github.com/saguiitay/OneDriveRestAPI

Comment: Это не та библиотека. Хотелось бы именно при помощи этой.
(https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напрямую, используя данную библиотеку, не получить данные пользователя. Но из неё можно получить `AccessToken`, а затем, используя его, получить данные пользователя при помощи REST API.
Имя пользователя можно получить примерно так:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite" };
var client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes) as OneDriveClient;
await client.AuthenticateAsync();
// забираем access_token
var AccessToken = client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
// запрашиваем данные авторизованного пользователя REST API
var uri = new Uri($"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={AccessToken}");

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
// получаем данные пользователя в JSON и разбираем его
string jsonUserInfo = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (jsonUserInfo != null)
{
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonUserInfo);
    string username = json["name"].ToString();
}
```

Email можно получить примерно так (не забудьте добавить `wl.emails` в список разрешений `scopes`)

```
string[] scopes = new string[] { "onedrive.readwrite", "wl.emails" };
var client = OneDriveClientExtensions.GetUniversalClient(scopes) as OneDriveClient;
await client.AuthenticateAsync();
var AccessToken = client.AuthenticationProvider.CurrentAccountSession.AccessToken;
var uri = new Uri($"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token={AccessToken}");

var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
string jsonUserInfo = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
if (jsonUserInfo != null)
{
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonUserInfo);
    string username = json["name"].ToString();
    string email = json["emails"]["account"].ToString();
}
```